# How can I get value of Text Component?

Tags: react-native

```
<Text>aircraft</Text>
```

I need to get `aircraft` in Text, and change the value of Text dynamically. How could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it like this (example: https://rnplay.org/apps/ACHJEQ)

`<Text ref={(elem) => this.textElem = elem}>Hello world!</Text>`

and then:
`console.log('textElem content', this.textElem.props.children);`

But you can't set it since it's a (read-only) prop.

Comment: It works. No way to set static `children`  of Text component?

Answer (score 0):

Well... various ways to do this.

For example:

```
<Text>{this.state.aircraftText}</Text>
```

and then just change the state variable. You could also implement it sth like:

```
<Text>{ (this.state.checkIfTrue) ? 'Boeing787' : 'Airbus 320' } </Text>
```

this checks if `this.state.checkIfTrue` results to true and displays either 'Boeing787' or 'Airbus 320'.

This should give you a first idea.

Comment: If I dont use `state`, how can I get the value?

Comment: how do you want to change the value? via textinput? or with a toggle?

<Text>{this.functionThatReturnsText() } </Text>

Comment: Thank you in advance. what you have mentioned are available actually, but I want to know if there exists a way to  change static text in `<Text>static text</Text>` without any bind like `state` in Text component.

Comment: @CoderGLM aha! in that case zvona's answer is the correct one.