# How to get Text component value onPress in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I'm a new react-native developer. I want to get the value of Text component using onPress and pass it to a function.

```
<Text onPress={()=>this.display}>Hello World</Text>


display= (text) =>{
    console.log(text);//this should print Hello world
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206819/react-nativehow-to-get-text-value-on-a-button-click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native:how to get Text value on a button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206819/react-nativehow-to-get-text-value-on-a-button-click)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method can be used to get text from a text onPress event

```
 <Text onPress={(event) => console.log(event._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children)} >{value}</Text>
```

Comment: FYI, for `onLongPress` apparently the correct fields are `event._targetInst.memoizedProps.children`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on React Native. I got some ideas from this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200552/how-can-i-get-value-of-text-component)

But I think you can set up a `ref` on the `Text` component

`<Text ref={(elem) => this.textElem = elem} onPress={()=>this.display}>Hello World</Text>`

For your event handler, you can do

```
display = () =>{
    console.log(this.textElem.props.children);//this should print Hello world
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onPress={(e) => console.log(e, word)}
```

> Class {dispatchConfig: {…}...} 'word'

word argument will carry the value of the component inner text, and the e will carry the event object.

practical example:

```
const wordSelected = (e, word) => {
    console.log(word);
  };

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) => wordSelected(e, word)}>
              <Text>print me out</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

> print me out

Answer (score 0):

You need can use the ref attribute to access the button's Text value.

```
<Text ref='myText'>This is my text</Text>
<Button onPress={()=>this.display(this.refs.myText.props.children)} title='Press Me'/>

//this should print Hello world
display= (text) =>{
    console.log(text);
}
```

Alternatively, just store it in a variable:

```
const myText = "This is my text"

<Text onPress={()=>this.display}>{myText}</Text>

display = () => {
     console.log(myText);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<Text onPress={()=>this.display('Hello World')}></Text>


display= (text) =>{
    console.log(text);//this should print Hello world
  }
```

Try this

Comment: Your code displays a hard-coded text 'Hello World', the code doesn't display the Text element value.