# touchableopacity onpress get text value

Tags: react-native

I have a touchableopacity component and onpress I need get the text value of the  component within it.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={validateAnswer} style={cssstyles2}>
                            <Text>{a}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>


const validateAnswer = (val) => {
        console.log('validateanswer - ', val)
    }
```

Not sure how to get the text value.

Comment: It is stored inside `a` variable. Can you probably add more context to your question?

Comment: {a} is a variable with a value..I need to get the value of that variable.

Comment: Where do you define ```a```? If it's a state, you can directly access it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you need as the value, you need to pass it this way. Wherever you're getting the value from

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => validateAnswer(val)} style={cssstyles2}>                            
    <Text>{a}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: how do I pass the value of text component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747744/how-to-get-text-component-value-onpress-in-react-naive

Comment: check out this thing

Comment: try this out  <Text onPress={(event) => console.log(event._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children)} >{value}</Text>

Answer (score 0):

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({val:'aa'})`
{this.state.val}

Honestly your question is very simple, I hope my answer will be help for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> validateAnswer(a)} style={cssstyles2}>
     <Text>
       {a}
     </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

const validateAnswer = (val) => {
      console.log('validateanswer - ', val)
}
```

I'm not sure why you have confused, as you have the variable what is inside the text view, just pass that and access it as a parameter in the validateAnswer function.

Answer (score 0):

The short explanation is because of JavaScript context. And the quick answer is to use onPress={() => validateAnswer(a)}

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => validateAnswer(a)} style={cssstyles2}>
  <Text>{a}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The longer answer is that onPress={validateAnswer} is shorthand for:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(event) => validateAnswer(event)} style={cssstyles2}>
  <Text>{a}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The event being passed into the onPress function is a React synthetic event. It wraps up the native browser button event that would normally be passed into a button event.

So you have access to the variable 'a' in your TouchableEvent, you just need to explicitly pass it to validateAnswer function. If you were to mistakenly think to try this: onPress={(a) => validateAnswer(a)} then you would be passing the React synthetic event to the function.